# Is there a word for a person who starts wars as a profession?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

I'm thinking of the character of Vizzini from "The Princess Bride", who starts wars on behalf of others. I'm looking for a term that's specific to that particular function, as opposed to a person who starts any kind of conflict or dissension e.g. an instigator.

Comment: Perhaps *warmonger*, by analogy to (say) *ironmonger*?

Comment: Please read [Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity?cb=1).

Comment: A related concept is a [false flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) operation.  It refers to the action rather than the person, though.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. Both from yourself (Jim Mack) and from @jeff-zeitlin. Both are close to what I'm looking for. I guess I was hoping for something more specific e.g. a "Mercenary" is someone who fights as a soldier for pay, and I was looking for a comparable term for one who starts wars for pay/profit. Warmonger is pretty close, but can refer to any person who is merely warlike or advocates war as a preferable course of action, but doesn't necessarily launch wars. Agent Provocateur, again, comes close but is too general. It may be that there is no explicit word, which is a shame.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility might be ***[agent provocateur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_provocateur)***. This term is principally used for a person that covertly attempts to incite others into committing or participating in illegal acts; in the context that you are asking about, the *agent provocateur* would be covertly attempting to set up conditions where the enemy would start the war without *apparent* provocation, possibly via [*false flag*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_flag) operations.

Answer (score 2):

**warmonger** may come close.

[Oxford Dictionary Definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/warmonger)

> A person who encourages or advocates aggression towards other countries or groups.